# How do i hide div elements and show an animation gif when the search button is clicked until the next page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanna hide the div having class "ToBeHiddenWhenSubmitted" and show an animation gif until the next page is loaded completely.

```
   <div class="front-paper" >
   <div class="container">

<form name="frm" method="GET" action="new.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
    <div class="input-append">
<input class="span6 input-custom" type="text" name="search" value=""  style="min-width:10px;"><br><br>


<div class="ToBeHiddenWhenSubmitted">
          <select class="btn btn-custom" name="view" id="views" data-native-menu="false" style="  height:42px; width:258px;">
      <option  value="linkfile">Show Files</option>
      <option  value="links">Show Links</option>
         </select>
<button type="submit" value="Search" id="clickme" class="btn btn-custom">Search</button>
        </div>


        </div>
    </form>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow's QA section isn't really designed for these sorts of questions. Your question is too broad; there are a ton of right answers. Try implementing this yourself, then, when you run into a problem *with a specific implementation*, come back, and ask your question.

Comment: I've seen all the answers and none of them works @Aeolingamenfel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as trivial as using `.show()` and `.hide()` on your targets within your existing `validateForm` function.

```
function validateForm (event) {
   $('.ToBeHiddenWhenSubmitted').hide();
   $('#animated-gif-selector').show();
   // whatever you already do in this function
}
```

If you are wondering how to continue the animation on the next page, you will have to do that *from that page*. To do that, hide the form or whatever on your next page by default and show the animated gif by default, then add an `ready` handler to swap their visibility:

```
$(function() {
    $('#animated-gif-selector').hide();
    $('.ToBeShownWhenPageFullyLoads').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) @Rob

Comment: It still shows when pressed back.. how do i stop it when pressed back? @Rob